# selecting specific link from ng-repeat CSS using robot framework

Tags: css, angularjs, robotframework

Webpage opens one popup, in that popup I have a list of pets. like dog, cat, fish, etc. each element is a link, and defined as below in css. but all of them have same values for all of the attributes, like div class, ng-bind, ng-click, etc. only one difference is text. I am not getting how to select a specific value using this text.
Both of the images are attached for reference. you can check the CSS code as well as the application popup. 
[Application popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEQf9.png) 
[Css Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02a03.png)

Please help me out....

Answer (score 1):

In the below xpath example I'm assuming that this list is uniquely referenced using the `@ng-repeat` attribute and with that the following reference will become a unique one: `//div[@ng-repeat='category in allCategory' and text() = 'Cow/Bull']`

Answer (score 0):

Partial matching of the text with xpath, just a little modification to the first answer.

```
//div[contains(text(),'Cow/Bull') and @ng-repeat="category in allCategory"]
```